# Comparing files within a folder

Tags: terminal, finder

I have a folder with many book files in different formats e.g. .txt, .epub, .rtf, etc.

Many of them are duplicates but have different names e.g.:

Brooks, Terry - Shannara 1 - The Sword of Shannara.txt

Brooks, Terry - Shannara 01 - The Sword of Shannara.txt

If I check these files with filemerge they are exactly the same file.

I have tried running several programs like Gemini on the folder in question with no results.

Every suggestion online seems to involve comparing two folders. I do NOT want to compare two folders. I only want to find the duplicate files within a directory or its sub-directories.

I was looking for a script or terminal command to loop through the folder(s) and show which files have the same content even though they may have different filenames, creation dates, modification dates, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[edit] - I should clarify that I want to find a way to compare two files even though they may be named differently but are of the same type. e.g. text files, or epub files. I do not wish to compare them between types a text file and an epub, of couse, would be different.

Comment: book.txt & book.epub etc are not going to have the same format or file contents, even if the contained text looks identical when you read the formatted result. I think you're going to have to sort by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fdupes` may be your solution. It can be installed via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with

```
brew install fdupes
```

If you don’t have homebrew, you can install homebrew with

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Running `fdupes -r <directory>` will list duplicate files within the directory, even if they’re not in the same folder. `fdupes` compares based on file contents, not names, so the names being different will not be a problem.

You can use the `-d` option to be prompted which files to keep (deleting all others), but I would suggest doing the deletions manually.

Comment: …but the contents will not be the same.

Comment: However that wil;l not show that ebbok.txt and ebook.epub are the same - and I suspect that if you had 2 epubs for the same book this would not find then as the metadata would differ. Duplicate txtx or possibly html rtf would work

Comment: In the example, both files are .txt. I took that to mean that duplicates are the same format, but different books are in different formats. As far as I know, it’s not possible to compare the text in epub and txt files.

Comment: I’m terms of epub metadata: I’ll leave it to someone else to write a program for parsing epub files and removing their metadata.

Comment: You could use Calibre to convert them all to plaintext, or even to sort them; once by author, once by title… but that would be more trouble than just dropping them all in one folder & going through it by hand

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I have fdupes installed and forgot I had it. It seems to be somewhat useful for some types of files like the texts and rtfs. However, I found a couple .epubs that appear to be exactly the same when viewed with Apple Books and fdupes does not find them. 

Comment: That is as expected you need meta data aware comparison programs. Eg calibre to start theprocess